# CKEditor 5 drag/drop location is invalid

Tags: ckeditor5

When implementing a custom drag and drop feature, we're seeing an error when trying to insert text at the drop location:

> Cannot set selection to given place.

The error points us here, though there isn't any additional information: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-model-selection-setTo-not-selectable

The code:

```
editor.editing.view.document.on('drop', function (evt, data) {

    var url = "https://www.url.com";

    editor.model.change(function (writer) {
        var insertPosition = data.dropRange.start;
        var linkedText = writer.createText(url, { linkHref: url });
        editor.model.insertContent(linkedText, insertPosition);
    });

});
```

Using `editor.model.document.selection.getLastPosition()` successfully inserts the text at the most recent cursor position, however for some reason `data.dropRange.start` is always invalid.